# What does the double vertical lines in the domain of a function mean?

Tags: graphing-functions

In my math textbook there was a question to sketch a possible graph in which it gave me some information on it. One of the questions gave me the domain and range of the function. The domain was [-5,||) and the range was [0,||). What does the double vertical lines mean here? Thanks!

Here is the picture:

[image: pic]

Comment: Are you sure it's not $11$? :P More seriously, I've never seen this notation before. It's likely defined earlier in the book.

Comment: ...or maybe you're supposed to fill in the blank!

Comment: Can you post an image of the original source?

Comment: I am sure it is not 11 and also sure you are not supposed to fill in the blank but thanks!

Comment: and btw this book is more like a workbook than a textbook.

Comment: Maybe it's absolute value?

Comment: Can you give us more context?  What is the function being talked about?  Can you show the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the symbol was meant to be $\infty$ (infinity) but was printed incorrectly.  If so, then the domain is $\{x:x\ge -5\}$ and the range is $\{y:y\ge 0\}$.